# MySQL left join and group_concat returning duplicate and cut-off data

Tags: java, mysql, join

I have a few tables from which I am trying to `SELECT` quite a lot of data. I have a table called `xguilds_guilds` which is the main table I am selecting data from. I also have a table called `xguilds_players`. All the players are connected to an entry in `xguilds_guilds`. The same goes for `xguilds_permissions` where every permission is connected to an `xguilds_guilds` entry.

My select query is as follows:

```
SELECT `xguilds_guilds`.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`xguilds_permissions`.`permission`) AS `permissions`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`xguilds_permissions`.`rank`) AS `ranks`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`xguilds_players`.`uuid`) AS `players`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`xguilds_players`.`rank`) AS `plranks`
FROM `xguilds_guilds`
  LEFT JOIN `xguilds_permissions` ON `xguilds_guilds`.`id` = `xguilds_permissions`.`guild`
  LEFT JOIN `xguilds_players` ON `xguilds_guilds`.`id` = `xguilds_players`.`guild`
WHERE `admin` = 0
GROUP BY `xguilds_guilds`.`id`;
```

However, for some reason the entries from the joined tables are not being selected correctly. For example, I have a guild with id 6 where I am expecting to select the following for the `players` column:

```
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5
```

However, it actually selects the following string, in which the uuids are constantly being repeated and cut off in the end:

```
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e606ddfd4cb9,
b9d9b3de-8e38-4277-999c-d95945658537,
f273e51a-a9b8-44af-a019-897e88509ae5,
030adc90-47a4-48ac-b713-e
```

I have no idea what is causing this strange behaviour. I don't have much experience with joining tables, which might be a problem in this situation. I have also tried the following query and that worked correctly:

```
SELECT `xguilds_guilds`.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`xguilds_players`.`uuid`) AS `players`
FROM `xguilds_guilds`
  LEFT JOIN `xguilds_players` ON `xguilds_guilds`.`id` = `xguilds_players`.`guild`
WHERE `guild` = 6
GROUP BY `xguilds_guilds`.`id`;
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a step back and look at your question and read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  Try to use DISTINCT on the uuid or at any column fir athat matter

Comment: Also you could read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Comment: @forpas How is that related to my question? There's no answer to accept

Comment: Good to know that you read it just in case you get answers.

Comment: @nbk the uuid's will be unique, but some players can have the same rank id (plranks).